# Перехватить текст c button asp.net js

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core

Кнопки создаются из списка по модели циклом.

```
if (reader["next_count"].ToString() != "0") {
     <button class="accordion">@reader["Division"].ToString()</button>
     <div class="panel">
```

После формирования списка из кнопок. Нужно при клике перехватить надпись которая на кнопке и через JS передать её на функцию обработки.

Не могу найти информацию как именно захватить текст на нажатой кнопке.

Comment: По какому событию это все должно происходить? По клику на кнопку?

Comment: Да по клику на кнопку

Comment: "Захватить" вам надо силами JS или asp?

Comment: Если есть возможность и так и так показать.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо разобрался. Текст с нажатой кнопки можно перехватить через .AJAX

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("button").click(function(){
         alert($(this).text());
    });
```